# how to backup database in vb.net mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

this is my code

Process.Start("C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe", "-u root clinicmanagementsystem -r""" & backupPath & "" & databasename & ".sql""")

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySqlBackup.NET, which is an alternative to mysqldump.

Official Website & Documentation > https://github.com/MySqlBackupNET/MySqlBackup.Net :

```
Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(constr)
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
cmd.Connection = conn
conn.Open
Dim mb As MySqlBackup = New MySqlBackup(cmd)
mb.ExportToFile("C:\backup.sql")
conn.Close
```